# How to access attributes in laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections, eloquent, attributes

I have this collection

```
Collection {#611
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => Payeur {#605
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "id"
      ]
      #attributes: array:11 [
        "id" => 1
        "prenom_payeur" => "aymen"
        "nom_payeur" => "larabi"
        "mobile_payeur" => "non"
        "telephone" => 230493212
        "observation" => "jeflolena"
        "adresse" => "jdjfnrll"
        "event_id" => 1
        "adherent_id" => 3
        "created_at" => "2019-12-22 14:57:43"
        "updated_at" => "2019-12-22 14:57:43"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to get the `nom_payeur` attributes from this collection. I did this many times before and I don't know why I get this error:

> (Property [nom_payeur] does not exist on this collection instance.)

I'm trying to get the attributes by doing this: `$payeur->nom_payeur` , $payeur is the collection.
Please help.

Comment: If `$payeur` is a collection, then you need to access an item within it. In your example, I'm guessing `$payeur[0]->nom_payeur` would be what you're looking for (but that only gives you the info for the first item, if there is one).

Comment: thank you i can access the attributes now

Answer (score 0):

```
try this hope its help
you have the collection and you try to access this property that is not possible beacuse in collection you can n't access element or attribute directly you have to use the array of index for this to access the poperty.

$payeur -> is collection this is incorrect way to access the property.

try this to access the attribute property.

$payeur[0]->nom_payeur
```

Comment: yeah but i can access only the first property

Comment: Yes you can access them with help of by itrate of loop because it creat the instance of array.